# Angular2 JSON Duplication Deletion

Tags: arrays, json, angular

I am working with a large JSON file holding information about instructors at my school. I want to be able to pull all the teachers names from this list so I can then put them into Firebase. However, whenever I loop over my JSON file and try to filter out all the duplicate teacher names I still end up with duplicates even when I try to do a second round of deletion. The JSON looks like this:

```
{
"Id": "1",
…
"Instructor": "name1, name2, name3", 
…
},
{
"Id": "2",
…
"Instructor": "name1", 
…
},
{
"Id": "3",
…
"Instructor": "name1, name2", 
…
}
```

As seen above sometimes there is just one name, other times there are multiple. I handle this though in my logic but no matter what I still end up with duplicates. If anyone can help me come up with a way to solve this it would be greatly appreciated. I'll add my code that I have already below.

```
public remove_duplicates(arr: any[]): any[] {
    let output: any[] = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      let instruc: any[] = arr[i].Instructor.split(',');
      for (let j = 0; j < instruc.length; j++) {
        let push: boolean = true;
        arr[i].Instructor = instruc[j];
        for (let k = 0; k < output.length; k++) {
          let i1: string = output[k].Instructor;
          let i2: string = arr[i].Instructor;
          if (i1.trim().localeCompare(i2.trim()) == 0) {
            push = false;
          }
        }
        if (push)
          output.push(arr[i]);
      }
    }

    console.log(output.length);
    for (let k = 0; k < output.length; k++) {
      for (let i = k + 1; i < output.length; i++) {
        if (new String(output[i].Instructor).valueOf().trim()
          === new String(output[k].Instructor).valueOf().trim()) {
          output.splice(i, 1);
        }
      }
    }

    for (let k = 0; k < output.length; k++) {
      console.log(output[k].Instructor);
    }

    console.log(output.length);
    return arr;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('courses.json').take(1)
      .map((res: Response) => res.json())
      .subscribe(
      data => {
        this.list = data;
      },
      err => console.log(err),
      () => this.remove_duplicates(this.list)
      );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything specific to Angular 2 that you're trying to do here. This is just vanilla JS.

Try something like this:

```
public remove_duplicates(arr) {
    let seen = {};
    let uniqueInstructorNames = [];
    arr.forEach(function(item) {
        let instructorNames = item.Instructor.split(',');
        Array.prototype.push.apply(uniqueInstructorNames, instructorNames.filter( name => { 
            return seen.hasOwnProperty(item) ? false : (seen[item] = true);
        }));
    });
    return uniqueInstructorNames;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! There was a little bit that needed to be changed to make it work 100%. Firstly I made it so it trimmed all the white space off of the elements in instructorsNames. Then you put seen[item] = true, but it needed to be seen[name]. Same for seen.hasOwnProperty(). When item was stored in seen it stored the entire JSON object which did not work. Once those changes were make it worked perfectly though, Thanks again!